# NodeJS cloud Openshift wont display my app

Tags: node.js, git, openshift

I've been struggling days just to upload my nodejs app on a cloud and i tried openshift because it seems nice and i've commited my folder and files into my github, i've created a ssh key and everything, i've pushed my app to my openshift app page, and it displays the normal guide on how to push your app to openshift instead of my app.

I've got no idea on how to fix it, i've done everything i could. I'm not getting any errors. When i do `git log`, it just says the author and date, no errors. Please, if somebody knows how to fix this, please tell me!

Server.js File

```
var express = require('express');
var static = require('node-static');

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

var app = express();
var config = require('./server/config/config')[env];

require('./server/config/express')(app, config);
require('./server/config/mongoose')(config);
require('./server/config/passport')();
require('./server/config/routes')(app);

app.listen(config.port);
console.log("Server running on port: " + config.port);
```

Comment: what do you mean by "wont display my app"?

Comment: it simply shows me the default page of an empty app

Comment: Then we have to see your code to figure out why it shows "default page of an empty app".

Comment: what do you mean code? do you mean like the commands i used to upload it to openshift?

Comment: the actual javascript files you pushed to OpenShift such as server.js

Comment: I've added it to the thread

Comment: What's the value of your config.port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it looks like you're not listening on the correct ip and port.  Here is  the code to get the correct ip/port on OpenShift:

```
// if on OpenShift, use OpenShift ip/port, else use your local ip/port
var ipAddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP || process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1";
var port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP || process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 3030;

   // The rest of the code
   :
   :


app.listen(port, ipAddress, function() {
  console.log('%s: Node server started on %s:%d ...',
                 new Date() ), ipAddress, port);
});
```

Comment: I've pasted this code and still nothing changes.. i think that im missing something or im not doing something right with openshift, here is the link to my repository if you need something https://github.com/Vasko-IV/rosiphotography

Comment: Everytime i make a git push, my repository changes everything i changed, but it simply wont display my website on openshift, its like i never had a website in the first place

Comment: When you push, output is printed on the screen.  Did you compare that URL from the output with the URL you're testing to see if they are the same?

Comment: when i git push it says:

Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects : 100% done
Writing objects : 100% done.
total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
to git@github.com:Vasko-IV/rosiphotography.git
f07fbbd..79417b9 master -> master

Thats all

Comment: You're not pushing your code on openshift.  You're pushing it on your github account.  You need to clone the project from the openshift.  To do that, login to your openshift account, select your app, under Source Code, copy the string "ssh://******", then from the command prompt the "git clone ssh://***** (replace ****** with the actually string you copied on openshift.  It should show something like this at the end: To ssh://xxxx2@yyy-zzz.rhcloud.com/~/git/your_app_name.git/
   cf943dc..b42e4fa  master -> master

Comment: ì'll try in a moments

Comment: i cloned it on openshift and when i tried doing git push it told me to use the name too so i did git push <name> , then it told me to use git push --set-upstream <name> master and from there it kept saying
fatal: invalid gitfile format: <name>
fatal: coult not read from remote reposityory

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repostory exists

Comment: would you mind doing it with teamviewer or something that shares screen? I'm new to this and i dont have much time! I'm sorry for the trouble, its just that its important.

Comment: I would love to do screen share to help you resolve the issue but I'm at work... I can to that in the evening.... however, I believe the problem you're having is ssh key issue.  You need to add your ssh key on openshift. to do that, login to your openshift account, select "Settings" tab, then select "Add a new key...", past the contend of your public key file (id_rsa.pub) into it

Comment: alright, i'll try, we cant do screen share since my time is different so i think it will be like really early on my time, where its evening with you, so i'll try to resolve it!

Comment: I'm on Pacific Daylight Saving Time (PDT) which is GMT-0700

Comment: My time zone is (UTC + 02:00) Athens, Bucharest, its 22:15 pm here, if you can, would you like to chat at skype? my name is 'haha2441' at skype, add me when you can, i'd be really thankful if we can sort this issue! its been a bother to me for ages, and its the last thing i have to do for my project.

Answer (score 0):

With OpenShift, you need to bind to a host-provided virtual `port` AND `IP` address.

Also, if your main entrypoint is not a script named `server.js`, then you'll need to configure your `package.json` in order to suit your needs.

More notes available here: https://www.openshift.com/blogs/run-your-nodejs-projects-on-openshift-in-two-simple-steps